# pip install giving platform not supported error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have following python distribution installed.

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

I downloaded `numpy-1.14.3+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

but upon installing, i got platform not supported error

```
C:\Users\HP\Downloads>pip install "numpy-1.14.3+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl"
numpy-1.14.3+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the error resolved.

python 3.6 supports only cp 36.

Comment: Perfect answer, I was facing same problem.